# Error: export ordinal too large: 104116

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, inkscape, ninja

I build the Inkscape from source code with:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
$ ninja install
```

And it return error as below.

```
[1002/1006] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/inkscape_base.dir/verbs.cpp.obj
[1003/1006] Linking CXX shared library bin\libinkscape_base.dll
FAILED: bin/libinkscape_base.dll src/libinkscape_base.dll.a
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe  -fopenmp -m64 -mms-bitfields -mthreads -mwindows -pthread -std=c++11 -g   -shared -o bin\libinkscape_base.dll -Wl,--out-implib,src\libinkscape_base.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles/inkscape_base.rsp  && cd ."
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Error: export ordinal too large: 104116
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

What will cause this error and how to solve it?

Note: I can build the Inkscape successfully without `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.

Comment: I tried to google something specific about this error but couldn't find anything appropriate in the first hits (except this question). Thus, what I know/found at least: Exported symbols in Windows DLLs can be identified by _name_ or by _ordinal number_. [MSDN: Export Functions from a DLL By Ordinal Rather Than By Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/aa278953(v=vs.60).aspx). It sounds like your build is somehow broken: broken .def file? Trying to export symbols by name instead? May be, this is the reason why it worked in debug (where names might be the default.)

Comment: I am new to cmake. How to export symbols by name?

Comment: IMHO, that's not an issue of CMake. How symbols are exported is part of the definition in the source code. (There might be files dedicated for MS compilers only.) One option is to provide an extra .def file. The other option is to use the MS specific extension [`__declspec(dllexport)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/a90k134d.aspx) in C++ source code. If I remember right it is also possible to export by names using a .def file. (I sometimes saw it in GTK+ sources but forgot the details meanwhile.)

Comment: It appears that at least for this tool chain, it considers the ordinal to be an unsigned 16-bit integer (range 0-65535) and therefore the ordinal number supplied it out of range.  I couldn't find anything in the documentation for [EXPORTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports) that specified the valid range of ordinals, but the [Export Ordinal Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx#export_ordinal_table) documentation confirms that the indices are 16-bit integers.

Comment: The linker if not instructed will choose to export any symbol and thereby overflow the 16bit enumeration limit. The linker have many options to reduce symbol export to a minimal subset.  https://users.rust-lang.org/t/gnu-ld-linker-errror-export-ordinal-too-large-xxxxx/84092

Answer (score 3):

There are too many symbols for compiling the DLLs, but I've managed to compile Inkscape with build style "Debug" and static linking, using the following command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -G Ninja ..
ninja install
```

Answer (score 0):

When building a DLL on Windows platform, there are two ways to export the functions from a DLL. One is by name, i.e. by using `__declspec(dllexport)` and the other is by ***ordinal*** number. The exported function's ordinal number is defined by appending it to the function's name in the `.def` file as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-def-files?view=msvc-170).
 For example:

```
LIBRARY   MYLIB
EXPORTS
   ActionA   @1
   ActionB   @2
   ActionC   @3
   ActionD   @4
```

The maximum ordinal number is defined by the [Microsoft PE and COFF format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#export-ordinal-table). It is a 16-bit integer with a maximum of 65535.
If the DLL is built with `.def` file, it is unlikely to hit the problem as it usually has less than maximum number of functions in the `.def` file. Same when the exported functions are explicitly decorated in the code. MSVC linker will not export other functions from the DLL. GNU linker however, in the absence of the `.def` file, exports all global symbols and hits the limit with this error message. An OS using the ELF format such as Linux, there is no such issue, because the limit is 32-bit or 64-bit depending on the build type, therefore it does not effect the shared libraries `.so`. 
 The fix is to define the `.def` file and pass it in the link step. Although, it is possible in GCC and CLANG to [specify the default visibility as hidden](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Exported-Symbols-of-Shared-Libraries.html) with `-fvisibility=hidden`, as of 2022 it is not supported on Windows.