# ld.exe: error: export ordinal too large: 84330

Tags: mingw, msys2

I am facing a linking error while compiling Ardour on Windows using MinGW. The error message is export ordinal too large: 84330. This issue arises during the linking stage of the build process.

What causes the "export ordinal too large" error in the context of compiling with MinGW on Windows?
Are there any known workarounds or configurations that can be applied to resolve this issue?

I see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135973/error-export-ordinal-too-large-104116) says you have to define the .def, but I have no .def file, do I need to create one?

I created a [CI build](https://github.com/kreijstal-contributions/ardour/blob/fork-masta/.github/workflows/c-cpp.yml), so anyone can see the exact steps of what I am doing.

[very verbose logs](https://github.com/kreijstal-contributions/ardour/actions/runs/7212666942/job/19650834494) You have to view them in raw mode.

Comment: The error means a symbol is being export with an ordinal number too big to fit in 16 bits (0-65535).
Solutions are usually related to exporting less symbols.
Maybe the build is exporting all symbols?
Normally one would specify `__declspec(dllexport)` for symbols that need to be exported.